# what are the main differences between jquery's official templating plugin and ICanHaz.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates, icanhaz.js

So far I've had nothing but good things to say about the jQuery plugin. It's been easy to use and has done what I need, and while that should be all I need to formulate an answer I'd like to hear from naysayers and users of other comparable templating engines to see what I might get annoyed with further down the track.

Comment: What? That's not a lolcat JS plugin? That's dumb.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the official jQuery templating plugin and have loved it. Their feature sets currently look pretty comparable. However, since ICanHaz is open-source if you are looking for more features down the road it might develop faster than the official jQuery template engine. However, if you are going for stability the official templating engine would likely be the better choice.

Just my 2 cents.